# vlc: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, vlc

When I build VLC, I run make, and got this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavformat.a(rmsipr.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

So I tried to add -fPIC in CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS, but after make I still got the same error.

Who can explain this?``

Comment: the complaint is that `ffmpeg` isn't built with `-fPIC`, you need to compile it with `-fPIC` before compiling your application.

Comment: when I use   ./configure --enable-shared and built with -fPIC and i got the simlar error: /usr/bin/ld: libavutil/color_utils.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Comment: Repeat : Which "Linux OS" are you using ?  ...... FFMPEG : `./configure --help` will show an option = --enable-pic

Comment: I am using fedora22,  which core is 4.2.5-201.fc22.x86_64. I  run ./configure --enable-pic and I can make and make install succeed. I mean built ffmpeg. But when I make vlc and i still got the same error. why?